# Having problems with google maps on Fragments layout

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I made an activity with google maps displayed, but I'd like to change it to Fragments, When I do that i get lots of errors.

I have problems with getMapAsync on the initmap method.

```
public class TAXIActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private MapView mapView;

    ArrayList LatitudeList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList LongitudeList = new ArrayList();
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_taxi, container, false);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_taxi);
/*
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        */
        getLocationPermission();


        //someMethod();


    }

    public void onViewCreated (View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        initMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("TAXIActivity", "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        someMethod();

        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            //mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);


        }

        //Log.d("TEST", "BBB");
        //String LatMarkers = LatitudeList.toString();
        //String LongMarkers = LongitudeList.toString();

        //Log.d("TEST", "AAA");
        /*
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(LatMarkers);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(LongMarkers);
            LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            //Log.d("TEST", "CCC");
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Camera Location"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
*/
        //Log.d("TEST", "DDD");

    }

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    void someMethod() {
        try {
            String jsonData = new TAXIAPI(client).execute().get();

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray RunningArray = object.getJSONArray("value");

            for (int i = 0; i < RunningArray.length(); ++i) {

                JSONObject objectInner = new JSONObject(RunningArray.getString(i));
                String Latitude = objectInner.getString("Latitude");
                String Longitude = objectInner.getString("Longitude");

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(Latitude);
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(Longitude);


                LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Taxi Location"));
                //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));//this will make camera focus on the last marker location
                //LatitudeList.add(Latitude);
                //LongitudeList.add(Longitude);

                Log.d("APIActivity", "  " + Latitude + "  " + Longitude);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        Log.d("TAXIActivity", "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {

                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d("TAXIActivity", "onComplete: found location!");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                    DEFAULT_ZOOM);

                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAXIActivity", "onComplete: current location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("TAXIActivity", "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom) {
        Log.d("TAXIActivity", "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    }

    private void initMap() {
        Log.d("TAXIActivity", "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(TAXIActivity.this);

    }

    private void getLocationPermission() {
        Log.d("TAXIActivity", "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("TAXIActivity", "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d("TAXIActivity", "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("TAXIActivity", "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    //initialize our map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.assignment1.TAXIActivity.initMap(TAXIActivity.java:199)
>           at com.example.assignment1.TAXIActivity.getLocationPermission(TAXIActivity.java:213)
>           at com.example.assignment1.TAXIActivity.onCreate(TAXIActivity.java:72)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting google map fragment before your fragment view is created.

Right now you're doing, `onCreate` then `getLocationPermission` then `initMap` then `.findFragmentById`. Your google map fragment is not initialized at this point, that's why you're getting a null pointer exception when calling `.getMapAsync`.

Two solutions. Move you `getLocationPermission` to `onViewCreated` or remove `initMap` from `getLocationPermission`.

I'd do the second one, because Google Map doesn't need location permission.